# Perl: Regex matching extra string

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following string cases:

- my $str = "Warehouse.13.s01e01.hdtv.xor.avi";
- my $str = "Warehouse.13.01x01.hdtv.xor.avi";
- my $str = "Warehouse.13.season01episode01.hdtv.xor.avi";

The delimiter(`.`) in the above cases can be replaced by `_ - \s`. Now to match the above cases I created the following regex and it works fine:

```
my $regex_object = qr{.*?\d{1,2}(?:e|edosipe)?[._\- x]?\d{1,2}(?:s|nosaes)?[._\- ]?(?=\d+)(.*)};
```

You can see I had to reverse the string to handle `\d+` because one should have a absolute length match in a look-behind so I converted it to look-ahead.

Now for the above cases the output is `Warehouse 13` which is my required output.

The problem now is if my `series name` doesn't contain `numbers(13,24)` I don't want my above regex to match and to make sure that I used `(?=\d+)` i,e if `s|season` is preceded by number or not.

Now if my `$str` is `'how.i.met.your.mother.s03e13.hdtv.mkv'` it matches the above regex and outputs

```
how.i.met.your.mother.s0
```

Now, I have no idea why it is matching this string even after using a look-behind and how to correct it.

Comment: Guys, if you are down voting me atleast give the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no idea why it is matching this string

```
.*?               "vkm.vtdh."
\d{1,2}           "31"
(?:e|edosipe)?    "e"
[._\- x]?         ""
\d{1,2}           "3"
(?:s|nosaes)?     ""
[._\- ]?          ""
(?=\d+)           "0"
(.*)              "0s.rehtom.ruoy.tem.i.woh"
```

A possible solution is to change (both)

```
\d{1,2}
```

to

```
\d{1,2}(?!\d)  # Don't match just "3" of "30".
               # Bonus: Can't match part of "123".
```

or

```
(?>\d{1,2})    # Prevents it from matching just
               # one digit if there are two.
               # Note: Can match "12" of "123".
```

Of course, then the `(?=\d+)` will cause the whole to fail. I have no idea why it's there in the first place. Maybe you meant `(?!\d+)`? (In both cases, the `+` is useless.)

Comment: The reason I used `(?=\d+)` is I wanted to make sure that I only match those string in which `s|season` is precided by `number`. If I use `(?!\d+)` than it will match the above `how.i....` case which I don't want it to.

Comment: I thought `{m,n}` always performed a greedy match and its non-greedy version is `{m,n}?`. Any reason why it is not matching `30` and instead matching only `3`. I am a beginner in regex.

Comment: It did match `30` at first, but that caused `(?=\d+)` to fail, so it backtracked.

Comment: But if it failed than it should have declared that this string does not match the user-defined pattern. Why it backtracked because when I read about perl-regex there was no mention to back-tracking.

Comment: You could also use `\d{1,2}+` aka `(?>\d{1,2})` instead of adding `(?!\d)`. It would prevent this backtracking.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks. I was not aware of `?>pattern` expression.

Comment: Without backtracking, a regex engine would be next to useless. For example, without backtracking, `.*?` would always match "". /// Not sure how you mised backtracking since there's an entire section named that in the [re docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: @ikegami: I am not that proficient in regex and I use it for basic stuff. So, I may be missed that. Thanks to you I found this. Todays target is to read the complete perl.re docs